# Populate a Combo box with form Aliases

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am attempting to populate a combo box with a list of form aliases, I can populate it with a list of form names but can't get the Aliases to work. I have this code in the Values of the combo box

```
var forms = database.getForms().iterator();
var tNames = new Array;
var cnt = 0;
while (forms.hasNext()){
    var form:NotesForm = forms.next();
    var temp = form.getAliases();
    if (temp != "" && temp != null) {
        tNames[cnt++] = temp;
    }
}
form.recycle();
return tNames.sort();
```

If I break it and return the value temp on the first time through I get a correct Aliase value, however, if I let it run all the way it gives an unexpected error when loading the page. I have tried several different ways to build the array tNames but none seem to work.

Comment: You should use the pattern Naveen outlines below. But the reason the code you listed throws an error is because your call to `form.recycle()` is outside of your `while` loop. Naveen properly moved that inside the loop, and you should too. :)

Comment: P.S. Stop using `new Array()`: http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-9AN5ZK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A form can have multiple aliases. So the statement `form.getAliases()` returns a Vector. When you run the loop only once then the variable `tNames` only contains a single value of `java.util.Vector` class which a combo box accepts. But when you let it run through all values the variable `tNames` becomes and Array of `java.util.Vector` which is not acceptable to combo box.

Try the below code:

```
var forms = database.getForms().iterator();
var tNames = new Array();
var cnt = 0;
while (forms.hasNext()){
    var form:NotesForm = forms.next();
    var temp = form.getAliases().toArray();
    tNames = tNames.concat(temp);
    form.recycle();
}
return tNames;
```

Comment: AS with most things the answer is usually simple. So thanks a lot.